# R assign a list of values to a list of objects

Tags: r, object

Thank you for trying to help. I am happy to be corrected on all R misdemeanors.

I am not sure that I was entirely clear with my earlier post as below, so I will hope to clarify:

In the R console, my calls 'use source (etc)' to a .R file
Code within the .R file uses variables (for e.g. 'extracted info' ) ex1, ex2, ex3. These may hold strings or (a string of) numbers pulled from text.

In line with your guidance I've renamed my function to 'reset' (and ?reset indicates no other occurrences) are in scope.  I'm passing both x and y which from outside the function:
    #send variables ex1, ex2, ex3 together with location, loc and parse, prs to be reset with 0
    reset(x<-c(loc,prs,ex1,ex2,ex3),y<-rep(c(0),length(x))) #repeats 0 in y variable as many times as there are entries for x

```
reset<-function(x,y){
print(c("resetting ",x," with ", y))
if (length(x) == length(y)) {x <- y
    print(paste(x,"=",y),sep="") #both x and y should now be equal (to y)
} else {
    paste("list lengths differ: x=",length(x)," y=",length(y),sep="")
}
```

}

Now both x and y are 0 but ex1, ex2 and ex3 still contain the previous values
I would like ex1, ex2 and ex3 all to be 0 before they are used in a subsequent section of code, so they don't contaminate extracted data with previous values such as:

```
loc<-str_locate(data[i],"=")
prs<-str_locate(data[i],",")
#extract data from the end of loc to before the occurrence of prs
ex1<-str_sub(data[i],loc[2]+1,prs[1]-1)
#cleanup
#below is simplified for example;
#in reality I wish to send ex1:ex(n) to be reset with values val1:val(n)
```

The desired outcome would be that back in the Rconsole >ex1 should now return 0.
Hope you can understand my dilemma and possibly help.

---

Say my code uses some variables to hold data extracted from a string using Stringr str_sub. The variables are temporary in that I use the values to construct other strings then they should be freed up to be used in an upcoming test: i.e. if (test==true){extract<-str_sub(string, start, end)}

For a later test, I would like extract==0; simple enough, but I have a few of these and would like to do it in one fell swoop.

I've used a for loop, but if there is a simpler way, please identify this.

My attempt is using a function:

```
#For variables loc, prs, ex1 and x2, set all values to 0
x<-assign(x<-c(loc, prs, ex1, ex2),y<-rep(c(0),length(x)))


#Function
assign <- function(x, y) {
    if(length(x)==length(y)){
        for (i in 1:length(x)){x[i]<-y[i]}
        print(c("Assigned",x[i]))
        return (x)
    } else { print (c("list lengths differ: x=",length(x)," y=",length(y)))
    }
}
```

The problem being that this returns x as 0, but the list of variables retain their values.

I'm a bit of a noob to both r and SO, so although I've benefitted from SO's bountiful advice on numerous occasions, this is my first question, so please be gentle.  I have searched this issue, but have not found what I need in a few hours now. Hope you can help.

Comment: There is already a function named "assign".  You may find it useful, but in any case you probably don't want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of naming a function `assign`. There is already one in base-r and you will create confusion.

There are a couple of problems with your function besides its name. First, you do not need the for-loop to replace x by y, as this is a basic vectorized operation. Just use `x <- y` ; second, your should wrap your message in `paste`.

```
asgn <- function(x, y) {
  if(length(x)==length(y)){
    ## This step is not needed, return(y) is better as @Rick proposed in their now deleted answer
    ## I am leaving it to show you how the for-loop is not needed
    x<-y
    return (x)
  } else { 
    print (paste("list lengths differ: x=",length(x)," y=",length(y)))
    return(x)
  }
}
```

Then, there are a couple of problems with your function call. You use `<-` instead of `=` to specify the arguments. They are only somewhat synonymous for assigning variables, but a function argument is another matter. Finally, you are trying to use `x` is the definition of `y` in the arguments (`length(x)`), but this is not possible, because it is not yet defined, so it is looking for x in the parent environment. You should test your function with `length(3)` instead.

```
x<-asgn(x=c(loc, prs, ex1, ex2),y=rep(c(0),length(3)))
```